# Any event available for backend to run a function in every page- Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, adminhtml

In **Magento2**,is there an event-observer available for the backend to run a function on every page?

Comment: adminhtml_block_html_before try this

Comment: What is your goal? Because there are many ways to approach this, from using a plugin, to an observer to adding something to the layout XML. Depending on the goal you might want to choose a different solution

Comment: I want to create  an admin page visit history function that's while  I  need an observer event  for the admin page

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml**

**events.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>

  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="admin_funcation_call" instance="VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer\AdminFunCall" />
    </event>
  </config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Observer**

**AdminFunCall.php**

```
  <?php

  namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer;

  use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
  use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

  class AdminFunCall implements ObserverInterface
  {
      protected $state;

      public function __construct(
          \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
      ) {
          $this->state = $state;
      }

      public function execute(Observer $observer)
      {
          $areaCode = $this->state->getAreaCode();
          if ($areaCode == "adminhtml") {
            // Add your code
          }
      }

  }
```

Comment: Instead of register observer in global area and check area inside, better to register observer to the same event but in adminhtml area with `etc/adminhtml/events.xml`.

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk Thanks Sir.